# How to find a Google API key in file?

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, api-key

I have been given a Google API key that is allegedly being used in one of our company's sites.  However, I cannot confirm which one.

Besides using the "Find in Files" feature in Notepad++, and literally searching each folder on the server, is there a simpler way to confirm which site is using a Google API key?

I cannot search the entire drive because it will freeze everything up.

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of the tags you put in. I even think it is off-topic to ask "how do I find a string in a file on the server" on SO.

Comment: Only legit way would be to "grep the whole drive".

Comment: Is that why you downvoted me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the projects from the server

1 - Try to search for google api call instead of key.
Open the project using IDE ( neatbeans or phpstorm )
Run a search for a (googleapis URL) with a little patient you cant spot where the api call is fired

2 - check package manager ex: package.json / bower.json / composer.json
if the application is using google sdk check the configuration required for the sdk and you will be able to find the key location if you follow the documentation

3 - ask for the google account used and get the key.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I will attempt everything you suggested.